# Troubleshoot asterisk cli

Tags: command-line-interface, asterisk

My asterisk box has verbose set to 3 but it is running really fast so I can't troubleshoot it easily!
I want to keep verbose = 3 and be able to see only activity related to on specific context!
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not posible.

But you can read log or use grep command to see only lines with some text in your log.

Default log is /var/log/asterisk/messages, settings in /etc/asterisk/logger.conf